# Is it possible to compare element values of a document on search in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I want to understand if marklogic has the ability to compare element values within a single document while performing a search i.e. cts:search.

For eg:

Consider a document as below

```
<root>
    <someTags></someTags>
    .
    .
    .
    <effectivePeriod>
        <dateTimeBegin>2009-01-16T00:00:00-05:00
        </dateTimeBegin>
        <dateTimeEnd>2009-01-16T00:00:00-05:00
        </dateTimeEnd>
    </effectivePeriod>
    .
    .
    .
    <otherTags></otherTags>
</root>
```

Let's imagine that there are a hundred thousand documents like the one above. How can I make a search that ensures I only pick up documents where the effectivePeriod.dateTimeEnd > effectivePeriod.dateTimeBegin?

Comment: Your document structure looks to have been eaten by the default HTML formatting. Can you please edit to reflect the actual structure?

Answer (score 1):

Construct your `cts:search()` with as specific criteria as possible, and then filter the results with a predicate:

```
cts:search(collection(), 
           cts:and-query())[root/effectivePeriod[dateTimeEnd gt dateTimeBegin]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [cts.periodCompareQuery](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.periodCompareQuery)?

Comment: Hi Sam, I will take a look at that. Do you have any pointers with respect to ML 7?

Comment: A hundred thousand documents really isn't that many.  In ML 7 you could easily write some XQuery or JavaScript code to loop through documents matching a cts search and further filter them with your criteria effectivePeriod.dateTimeEnd > effectivePeriod.dateTimeBegin.  There are other techniques you could use if you need to scale the query to millions or billions of documents.